# Travis CI with GitHub Pages / Linkchecker

Tags: github, jekyll, travis-ci, github-pages, link-checking

I am hosting pages on GitHub Pages. These use Jekyll, but that shouldn't matter.

Since we have source code management for the web pages and even a publishing and hosting... why not add CI!

Is there a best practice for implementing a link checker using Travis CI scenario. Also, practically, is this the "right" thing to do since may use a lot of resources?

Thank you!

Comment: Or let me know what's wrong here, please

Comment: Did you tried https://github.com/endymion/link-checker ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the official document of Jekyll.
(http://jekyllrb.com/docs/continuous-integration/)

Comment: This is a comment, not answer